# _addColumnFilterToCollection not working in page 2

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, filter

Here is a method in a observer to add a custom column in customer grid, and use custom filter collection function to filter. The problem is when i search billing_company for example test in page 1, it works, but not works in page 2.

[image]

[image]

```
    public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            if ($event->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid) {

                $this->_grid = $event->getBlock();
                $this->_collection = $this->_grid->getCollection();

//echo count($this->_collection);
                $this->_collection->addAttributeToSelect('billing_company')->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

                $this->_grid->addColumnAfter(
                    'billing_company',
                    array(
                        'header' => Mage::helper('Test_Admin')->__('company_name'),
                        'index'  => 'billing_company',
                        'type'   => 'text',
                    ),
                    'entity_id'
                );

                $this->_grid->sortColumnsByOrder();
                // rebuild the filters
                $filter = $this->_grid->getParam($this->_grid->getVarNameFilter(), null);
                if (is_null($filter)) {
                    return $this;
                }
                $this->_collection->clear();
                if (is_string($filter)) {
                    $data = $this->_grid->helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);
                    $this->_setFilterValues($data);
                } else {
                    if ($filter && is_array($filter)) {
                        $this->_setFilterValues($filter);
                    }
                }
                // force a reload of the collection
                $this->_collection->load();

            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            mage::logException($e);
        }

        return $this;

    }

    protected function _setFilterValues($data)
    {
        foreach ($this->_grid->getColumns() as $columnId => $column) {
            if (isset($data[$columnId]) && (!empty($data[$columnId]) || strlen($data[$columnId]) > 0)
                && $column->getFilter()
            ) {
                $column->getFilter()->setValue($data[$columnId]);
                $this->_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {

        if ($this->_collection) {

            $field = ($column->getFilterIndex()) ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();

            if ($column->getFilterConditionCallback()) {
                call_user_func($column->getFilterConditionCallback(), $this->getCollection(), $column);
            } else {
                $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();

                if ($field && isset($cond)) {
                    $this->_collection->addAttributeToFilter($field, $cond);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: The filter is working correct as per Magento. You cannot see results because there are only two results for your filter and these two results are on page 1. So, you will not see any record on page 2.

Comment: no, it is wrong, it should be only one page to be displayed, and if i search in page 2, it will not display the result

Comment: You don't understand my question , now if i 1) search on page 2, the result has no record 2) if only has two records, the pager should be 1/1

Comment: Can you add the code using which you added column in your grid.

Comment: only this function to add the column, the event i use adminhtml_block_html_before